# How to find two structural breaks dates in a linear regression using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, regression

I have plotted stock price cumulative returns.  An example is shown below:

[image]

In this plot, it is clear to see that there are two structural breaks. Because I want to specify the exact date of these two structural breaks, I want to run the following regression in MATLAB:

[image]

The two breakpoints `t1` and `t2` can be obtained by minimizing over all possible pairs between `t1`, `t2` the sum of the squared residuals, but I do not know how to do this in MATLAB.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: StackOverflow does not support LaTeX.  Can you use an Online TeX edtior and point us to the image?  I'll modify your post.  Also, take a look at `pdist` and `pdist2` to get you started for minimizing sum of squared error residuals.

Comment: How are these points defined?  Are these matrices? Vectors?  You need to provide more information on **how** your data is structured